# Android 32-bit ARM OOM killer triggered unexpectedly

Tags: android, linux, memory, out-of-memory

I am running a relatively simple program that calls mmap() repeatedly to obtain 100MB+ memory (and touch every single page of them). The problem is that this program always triggers the OOM killer in the kernel (based on 3.4) even though there are still plenty of physical pages (2G RAM in total and 1.6G+ is free).

I do see that these two lines of output seem to indicate that there are not many small free blocks left in HighMem (but many big ones are available still):

```
Normal: 1220*4kB 1034*8kB 791*16kB 547*32kB 289*64kB 130*128kB 39*256kB 9*512kB 5*1024kB 3*2048kB 149*4096kB = 714608kB
HighMem: 1*4kB 0*8kB 1*16kB 0*32kB 1*64kB 1*128kB 1*256kB 1*512kB 1*1024kB 2*2048kB 254*4096kB = 1046484kB
```

But I just can't wrap my head around this when the system also says that there are `524288 pages of RAM` and `440840 free pages` (most are free).

Below is the detailed output. Any help is appreciated!

```
test_program invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x0, order=0, oom_adj=-17, oom_score_adj=-1000
[<c0011074>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xe0) from [<c00813f0>] (dump_header.isra.16+0x74/0x18c)
[<c00813f0>] (dump_header.isra.16+0x74/0x18c) from [<c0081674>] (oom_kill_process.part.19.constprop.20+0x44/0x268)
[<c0081674>] (oom_kill_process.part.19.constprop.20+0x44/0x268) from [<c0081d64>] (out_of_memory+0x328/0x3f4)
[<c0081d64>] (out_of_memory+0x328/0x3f4) from [<c0081ef0>] (pagefault_out_of_memory+0xc0/0x154)
[<c0081ef0>] (pagefault_out_of_memory+0xc0/0x154) from [<c00120e0>] (do_page_fault+0x1bc/0x244)
[<c00120e0>] (do_page_fault+0x1bc/0x244) from [<c0008364>] (do_DataAbort+0x34/0x98)
[<c0008364>] (do_DataAbort+0x34/0x98) from [<c000d3f4>] (__dabt_usr+0x34/0x40)
Exception stack(0xed479fb0 to 0xed479ff8)
9fa0:                                     aee1cffc aeec2000 0db4da5f aee1d000
9fc0: 00000000 0001b184 00000040 00000059 00000000 00000000 00000000 be9ccacc
9fe0: 00000064 be9cc9f0 0000b037 0000830c 80000030 ffffffff

Mem-info:
Normal per-cpu:
CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd: 157
HighMem per-cpu:
CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  39
active_anon:37727 inactive_anon:936 isolated_anon:0
 active_file:4108 inactive_file:25830 isolated_file:0
 unevictable:1 dirty:12 writeback:0 unstable:0
 free:440273 slab_reclaimable:1457 slab_unreclaimable:2172
 mapped:12414 shmem:944 pagetables:752 bounce:0

Normal free:714608kB min:3512kB low:5052kB high:5932kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:788kB inactive_file:1632kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:772160kB mlocked:0kB dirty:48kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:5828kB slab_unreclaimable:8688kB kernel_stack:2032kB pagetables:3008kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 10223 10223

HighMem free:1046484kB min:512kB low:3128kB high:4616kB active_anon:150908kB inactive_anon:3744kB active_file:15644kB inactive_file:101688kB unevictable:4kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:1308608kB mlocked:4kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:49656kB shmem:3776kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? no
lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0
Normal: 1220*4kB 1034*8kB 791*16kB 547*32kB 289*64kB 130*128kB 39*256kB 9*512kB 5*1024kB 3*2048kB 149*4096kB = 714608kB
HighMem: 1*4kB 0*8kB 1*16kB 0*32kB 1*64kB 1*128kB 1*256kB 1*512kB 1*1024kB 2*2048kB 254*4096kB = 1046484kB
30879 total pagecache pages
0 pages in swap cache
Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/1
Free swap  = 0kB
Total swap = 0kB
524288 pages of RAM
440840 free pages
9650 reserved pages
3629 slab pages
59279 pages shared
0 pages swap cached
```